# Operating on a vector of cells and inseriting it into a cell array MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

What I'm working with is a cell array M, with say nxm cells.  I read in column d, colD, to edit the strings contained therein.

I changed these cells using char(colD), and now have a vector of strings that I'm done editing.  Converting back to cells using cell(colD) I need to insert the vector into the cell array.  Is there a more efficient way of doing it than looping?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `newM = cellfun(@(x) char(x), M, 'UniformOutput', false)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
newM = cellfun(@(x) char(x), M, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

shamelessly stolen from @Ansari